# Issues in Python Documentation Guidelines

Tags: discussion, documentation

Python's documentation has a topic "[Meta: Documentation Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/394/meta-documentation-guidelines)". Looking at its [history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/2994), I see that it was created on April 7th with a pinned *example*:

> These are just proposals not recommendations. Feel free to edit
>   anything here if you disagree or have something else to mention.
>
> Eventually this could be included or linked in the Hello World-topic.

At that time, another example was also added about how to include the outputs to examples. It was edited a couple of times but basically the recommendation was to put outputs in comments. For example,

```
x = 7
x
# Out: 7
```

One of my examples was edited citing this recommendation. It made sense to me so I decided to edit my other examples as well. I wanted to link that example but I saw that it was [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/33396).

It had 5 contributors and 8 upvotes before deletion and got deleted by 1 suggestion (as a result of an improvement request) and 1 approval (it had also 1 rejection).

Can we treat this topic like Meta where we upvote and downvote suggestions? If so, should we add the example again? Or is it too early to have rule-looking guidelines? Should these be discussed somewhere else?

Update: The topic got [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/85072).

Comment: This points to a broader problem: there's no place for editors to discuss what Docs should look like.  (Compare most wikis' talk/discussion pages.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering the more general question (not specific to Python):

> "Or is it too early to have rule-looking guidelines?"

Beta is the perfect time to start [talking about what Docs in a tag should look like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329173/). If a tag's community has some tentative guidelines, let's write them down so we can coordinate how we contribute to Docs; discuss it; and update the guidelines over time.

Maybe we will find that, in light of how we want to use Docs for a particular tag, some Docs features ought to be added or overhauled. Better to get to that point during beta than to wait.

## Guidelines vs rules

We can have a guideline like

> Handle x however you like, but keep in mind y and z.

*This is the essentially the opposite of a rule.* It offers some guidance to editors and sends a message to reviewers that "you're doing x wrong" is not a good reason to reject a contribution to Docs.

That's the stance taken in both the [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) guidelines for displaying output, like "Hey, here are some options for distinguishing between input and output. Please think about it and pick one."

## Where to put such meta guidelines?

Oh, I don't know, maybe [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329686/)? They don't belong as examples in Docs, but until we have a better place for them, I think they should not be deleted simply for being meta. We may never get a better place for them... as seems to be the case for [tag-specific MCVE guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).