# Where can we discuss guidelines for Documentation on a per-tag basis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

So I took a closer look at a tag in Documentation I happen to know well, PHP.

At the moment, there seems to be little of value there. :(

Take pretty much any section there and look through the examples. Most of the content is a mere repetition of things already perfectly adequately covered by the official docs. (e.g. "Search an Array" in [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/204/arrays#t=201607231711540894543) vs. [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)).

At least part of this seems to be lack of a consensus on what we want Documentation for that tag to actually *be*.

What we seem to have is an unmoderated rush of users, and the assumption that if something is already well documented elsewhere, things are going to sort themselves out. They aren't - there's too much rep to be made in copying / mirroring trivial content (and many users are surely contributing in good faith, believing that mirroring the official docs 1:1 is the *point*).

When, where and how are we going forge out guidelines for what types of examples we want - what might actually *create value* instead of mindlessly copy&pasting low-level content (in spirit if not in literal fact) that is already perfectly documented elsewhere?

This will vary massively from tag to tag, depending on the state of the tag's official documentation and third-party resources.

ImageMagick, to pick a random example, has a [superb repository of examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/) that is going to be hard to match. I fear the day someone discovers there's loads of rep to be made by creating an ImageMagick examples section.

What communication there is at the moment, seems to take part in the approve/reject process, with disheartening results.

How is all this going to work?

Comment: While we're discussing guidelines, let's also include style guidelines. Right now, everyone is following their own idea of how something should be formatted and presented, giving a widely different look from one example/topic to another.

Comment: This is why I want barriers on who can participate on Docs... is easier to coordinate a handful users than a whole swarm of it.

Comment: Not only do wikis have talk/discussion pages for individual pages, large ones usually have a dedicated namespace of administrative/project/community pages where editors can coordinate.  Docs needs at least the former.  Perhaps meta can serve as the latter, if we can actually get editors over here to discuss things.

Comment: Chat is where the back-room dealing is supposed to place around here, right? I created http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118148/apple-docs-organization in response to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329306/ We'll see...

Comment: These are two different issues - while quality control is starting to seem imperative, style guides are open war zones better left alone (much like Q&A, the OP's style choice should be good enough unless the style obfuscates or confuses the meaning).

Comment: I guess there's some other chat rooms too. The main Docs chat room has a pinned message by Quill linking to a list: https://gist.github.com/The-Quill/e29cfd24bd078f8bebba920ce5cbf7da

Comment: I agree about the lack of space for discussions. But I disagree about ImageMagick. Because their example repository is very complete, it's huge which makes it hard to find what you are looking for. What makes it even harder is that, as a beginner, you don't speak their language. So an IM tag on SO Doc would cover the most common beginner cases, using more understandable words. I use IM for "Photoshop automation" and some things that are very easy to do with Photoshop are very painful and complicated to write down with IM. Not even talking about optimization.

Answer (score 6):

I right now have proposed a (more concrete) feature-request with a solution to this problem:

[Allow for Area 51-like mini-metas per documentation tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329686/allow-for-area51-like-mini-metas-per-documentation-tag)